# How can I remove the effect of the first Radiobutton when selecting different Radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I want to organize the GUI for my code, that has 2 sections. I'm organizing it by adding `Radiobutton`s, where when one is selected, it displays "Section 1" only. And when the other `Radiobutton` is selected, it should undisplay "Section 1", and display only "Section 2".

This is the idea, and it is all going well, except that if I change `Radiobutton` selection, it displays both sections.

How can I make it display only one at a time?

This is a sample code that can be run:

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()


class Window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Test")
        self.master.geometry('1000x700')

        self.Radio=Label (self.master, text="Select Method", bg='Lavender')
        self.RadioFrame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=150, labelwidget=self.Radio, bg='lavender')
        self.RadioFrame.place(x=200, y=35)

        selection = IntVar()
        selection.set(0)
        r1 = Radiobutton(self.RadioFrame, text="Option 1", variable=selection, value=1, command=lambda: Clicked(selection.get()), bg='lavender').pack()
        r2 = Radiobutton(self.RadioFrame, text="Option 2", variable=selection, value=2, command=lambda: Clicked(selection.get()), bg='lavender').pack()

        def Clicked(variable):

            if selection.get() ==1:
                self.label_1=Label (self.master, text="label 1", bg='lavender')
                self.label_1Frame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=90, labelwidget= self.label_1, bg='lavender')
                self.label_1Frame.place(x=490, y=35)

            elif selection.get() ==2:
                self.label_2=Label (self.master, text="label_2", bg='lavender')
                self.label_2Frame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=60, labelwidget= self.label_2, bg='lavender')
                self.label_2Frame.place(x=490, y=340)

#root.mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to consider a different way of organizing your GUI that would probably take up less space on the screen: See [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136873/355230).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
try:
    self.any_widget.destroy()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

To destroy any widget.
So, I have corrected your code:

```py
from tkinter import *  

def main():    
    root = Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()


class Window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Test")
        self.master.geometry('1000x700')

        self.Radio=Label (self.master, text="Select Method", bg='Lavender')
        self.RadioFrame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=150, labelwidget=self.Radio, bg='lavender')
        self.RadioFrame.place(x=200, y=35)

        selection = IntVar()
        selection.set(0)
        r1 = Radiobutton(self.RadioFrame, text="Option 1", variable=selection, value=1, command=lambda: Clicked(selection.get()), bg='lavender').pack()
        r2 = Radiobutton(self.RadioFrame, text="Option 2", variable=selection, value=2, command=lambda: Clicked(selection.get()), bg='lavender').pack()

        def Clicked(variable):
    
            if selection.get() ==1: 
                self.label_1=Label (self.master, text="label 1", bg='lavender')
                self.label_1Frame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=90, labelwidget= self.label_1, bg='lavender')
                self.label_1Frame.place(x=490, y=35)
                try:
                    self.label_2Frame.destroy()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass

            elif selection.get() ==2:
                self.label_2=Label (self.master, text="label_2", bg='lavender')
                self.label_2Frame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=60, labelwidget= self.label_2, bg='lavender')
                self.label_2Frame.place(x=490, y=340)
                try:
                    self.label_1Frame.destroy()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass

#root.mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Try this one.

Comment: user17356493: It's somewhat wasteful (as well as unnecessary) to repeatedly create and destroy essentially the same widget(s) more than once which is what would happen using this approach when switching back and forth between the sections. IMO the way it's done in @acw1668's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136873/355230) is the  better way to handle something like this.

Comment: Yes, I also think so.

Answer (score 2):

You created new `LabelFrame` when radiobutton is clicked.  You should create the two label frames first without showing them, and then show the one based on the selection of radiobuttons:

```py
class Window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Test")
        self.master.geometry('1000x700')

        self.Radio=Label (self.master, text="Select Method", bg='Lavender')
        self.RadioFrame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=150, labelwidget=self.Radio, bg='lavender')
        self.RadioFrame.place(x=200, y=35)

        selection = IntVar()
        selection.set(0)
        r1 = Radiobutton(self.RadioFrame, text="Option 1", variable=selection, value=1, command=lambda: Clicked(selection.get()), bg='lavender').pack()
        r2 = Radiobutton(self.RadioFrame, text="Option 2", variable=selection, value=2, command=lambda: Clicked(selection.get()), bg='lavender').pack()

        # create the two label frames without showing them
        self.label_1=Label (self.master, text="label 1", bg='lavender')
        self.label_1Frame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=90, labelwidget= self.label_1, bg='lavender')

        self.label_2=Label (self.master, text="label_2", bg='lavender')
        self.label_2Frame=LabelFrame(self.master, width=230, height=60, labelwidget= self.label_2, bg='lavender')

        def Clicked(selected):

            if selected ==1:
                self.label_1Frame.place(x=490, y=35) # show label frame 1
                self.label_2Frame.place_forget() # hide label frame 2

            elif selected ==2:
                self.label_1Frame.place_forget() # hide label frame 1
                self.label_2Frame.place(x=490, y=340) # show label frame 2
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate you time :)